# API to return a subset of fields after joining 2 models

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models namely,

**ModelA:**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    common_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model_a_field1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model_a_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    model_a_field3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model_a_field4 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    model_a_field5 = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = modelA
```

**and ModelB**:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    common_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model_b_field1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model_b_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    model_b_field3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model_b_field4 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        db_table = modelB
```

I need to create an API such that on accessing the endpoint, I have to return the below fields from both the models which have common_field as the common column linking them:

*common_field, model_a_field1, model_a_field2, model_a_field5, model_b_field2, model_b_field3*

I know I can do this by doing the below:

**Model**

```
class ModelC(models.Model):
    common_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model_a_field1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model_a_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    model_a_field5 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model_b_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    model_b_field3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

**Serializer:**

```
class ModelCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialaizer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views:**

```
class ModelCList(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = ModelC.objects.raw('select modelA.id, modelA.common_field, modelA.model_a_field1, modelA.model_a_field2, modelA.model_a_field5, modelB.model_b_field2, modelB.model_b_field3 from modelA inner join modelB on modelA.common_field = modelB.common_field')
    serializer_class = ModelCSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        return self.list(request)
```

**Is there any other way to achieve this. Especially if there is a way without having to write a query as in the above?**

Answer (score 0):

> `select modelA.id, modelA.common_field, modelA.model_a_field1, modelA.model_a_field2, modelA.model_a_field5, modelB.model_b_field2, modelB.model_b_field3 from modelA inner join modelB on modelA.common_field = modelB.common_field`

Have u tried executing this though ? I doubt it works.

same query in django's ORM could look like:

```py
common_field = "blahblah"
queryset_a = ModelA.filter(common_field=common_field)
               .values("id", "common_field", "model_a_field1", "model_a_field2", "model_a_field5")
queryset_b = ModelB.filter(common_field=common_field)
               .values("model_b_field2, model_b_field3")


from itertools import zip_longest

final = [{**dicta, **dictb} for dicta, dictb in zip_longest(queryset_a, queryset_b, fillvalue={})]]
```

But this approach has many disadvantages so the point is that if you are doing it this way, there's something wrong with your database design.

> which have common_field as the common column linking them

In SQL, if you want to link 2 tables and then join them, you should define a *relationship* between the 2 tables using a foreign key. Since you have only mentioned very generic models in your question, this is not something I can help you with but I'd recommend you to read about django's [Relationships in Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#relationships).

Comment: Since the tables are already present I cannot create a foreign key relationship. Also, the above solution doesn't work for me. I suspect there is a way to achieve the query I wrote with Django ORM using annotate but somehow unable to figure it out.